# How to Receive JSON sent from client side to server Side in cakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am receiving A String instead of Json. i am accessing received json using 
`$this->request->input()`

My Add method is as follows:

```
function add()
{
    if (!empty($this->request->input())) {  
        $this->loadModel('crud');
        if($this->crud->save( $this->request->input() ) )
        {  
            $this->Flash->set("Operation Completed.");
            $this->set('message',"Your user data has been saved.");
        }
        else
            $this->set('message',"Error.");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes.. please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the docs, it's all well explained. `Request::input()` by default returns data in raw string format, if you need it to be converted, pass a callback to the method to handle that, for example [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
$this->request->input('json_decode');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request & Response Objects > XML or JSON Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#xml-or-json-data)**
- **[API > Cake\Network\Request::input()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Request.html#_input)**

Comment: i have read it.. but using `$this->request->input('json_decode');` returns NULL

Comment: Then PHP thinks that your JSON is invalid, check **http://php.net/json_last_error_msg** and inspect your data @JamshaidTariq

Comment: sending json using postman.. `{ "first_name":"jamshaid" , "last_name":"tariq"}`

Comment: If that would be what is being retrieved, then you wouldn't get `NULL`, as that is totally valid JSON. You should debug what exactly `Request::input()` (without conversion) returns, check for whitespaces, hidden characters, etc... also make sure that the `json_decode` function actually exists. And please note that this is really a totally different problem, if you need help with debugging, then you should ask a new question and add appropriate details, or maybe even better ask on IRC where you can have a long "back and forth" conversation. @JamshaidTariq

Comment: upon reviewing my JSON i came to know that i was trying to send json with single quote instead of double quote. now `$this->request->input('json_decode');` returns an object. but i am getting error **Call to undefined method stdClass::errors()** when i use `$this->crud->save( $this->request->input('json_decode'))` Statement.

Comment: @JamshaidTariq That's because that's not how saving works, the save method expects an object that implements `EntityInterface`. Again, a totally different problem, please ask a new question if you need help with converting JSON input into a saveable entity.

Comment: Thank you all for such detailed help. i have solved my problem using `$crudTable = TableRegistry::get('crud'); `   
    `$this->crud->save( $crudTable->newEntity( $data ) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$this->crud->save( json_decode($this->request->input()))`

or save the input to a different variable and then try to save that variable as below

```
$input = json_decode($this->request->input())
$this->crud->save($input)
```